# Can't attach a contact to a customer

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to add some contacts and attach them to an existing customer. I am sending what I think are the right messages, I'm not getting any errors and the contacts are being created but they are not being attached to the customer. Please can you help me find the problem?

Here's the request to add the contacts:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Header>
        <passport xmlns="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <email xmlns="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">*****</email>
            <password xmlns="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">********************</password>
            <account xmlns="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">*****</account>
            <role internalId="3" xmlns="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
        </passport>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <upsertList xmlns="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <record externalId="20582-1" xsi:type="q1:Contact" xmlns:q1="urn:relationships_2014_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com">
                <q1:firstName>Sam</q1:firstName>
                <q1:title>Accounts / Oxford</q1:title>
                <q1:phone>01865 787221</q1:phone>
                <q1:subsidiary internalId="1"/>
            </record>
            <record externalId="20582-2" xsi:type="q2:Contact" xmlns:q2="urn:relationships_2014_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com">
                <q2:firstName>Ann Ohalan</q2:firstName>
                <q2:title>Scotland contact = PO- 8109983</q2:title>
                <q2:phone>0141 8109550</q2:phone>
                <q2:subsidiary internalId="1"/>
            </record>
            <record externalId="20582-3" xsi:type="q3:Contact" xmlns:q3="urn:relationships_2014_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com">
                <q3:firstName>Zoe Andrews</q3:firstName>
                <q3:title/>
                <q3:phone>01865 719671</q3:phone>
                <q3:subsidiary internalId="1"/>
            </record>
            <record externalId="20582-4" xsi:type="q4:Contact" xmlns:q4="urn:relationships_2014_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com">
                <q4:firstName>Jane Williams</q4:firstName>
                <q4:title>Northampton contact=PO</q4:title>
                <q4:phone>01604 235733</q4:phone>
                <q4:subsidiary internalId="1"/>
            </record>
            <record externalId="20582-5" xsi:type="q5:Contact" xmlns:q5="urn:relationships_2014_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com">
                <q5:firstName>Ann Direct Dail</q5:firstName>
                <q5:title/>
                <q5:phone>0141 8109983</q5:phone>
                <q5:subsidiary internalId="1"/>
            </record>
        </upsertList>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here's the request to attach the contacts to the customer:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Header>
        <passport xmlns="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <email xmlns="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">******</email>
            <password xmlns="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">********************</password>
            <account xmlns="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">*****</account>
            <role internalId="3" xmlns="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
        </passport>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <update xmlns="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <record internalId="21469" xsi:type="q1:Customer" xmlns:q1="urn:relationships_2014_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com">
                <q1:contactRolesList>
                    <q1:contactRoles>
                        <q1:contact type="contact" externalId="20582-1"/>
                        <q1:role internalId="-10"/>
                    </q1:contactRoles>
                    <q1:contactRoles>
                        <q1:contact type="contact" externalId="20582-2"/>
                        <q1:role internalId="-20"/>
                    </q1:contactRoles>
                    <q1:contactRoles>
                        <q1:contact type="contact" externalId="20582-3"/>
                        <q1:role internalId="-20"/>
                    </q1:contactRoles>
                    <q1:contactRoles>
                        <q1:contact type="contact" externalId="20582-4"/>
                        <q1:role internalId="-20"/>
                    </q1:contactRoles>
                    <q1:contactRoles>
                        <q1:contact type="contact" externalId="20582-5"/>
                        <q1:role internalId="-20"/>
                    </q1:contactRoles>
                </q1:contactRolesList>
            </record>
        </update>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here's the response to the latter request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <platformMsgs:documentInfo xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <platformMsgs:nsId>WEBSERVICES_3640472_1130201432731294637026381_400c6ccd4d3d75</platformMsgs:nsId>
        </platformMsgs:documentInfo>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <updateResponse xmlns="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <writeResponse>
                <platformCore:status isSuccess="true" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
                <baseRef xsi:type="platformCore:RecordRef" type="customer" internalId="21469" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
            </writeResponse>
        </updateResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The Contacts list for the customer remains empty:

[image]

I can select the contacts from the list and attach them manually with success.

The contacts are shown in the global contact list without a customer:
[image]

P.S. How would I search SuiteAnswers or the API reference to find how to do this myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that well versed with SuiteTalk but can you not populate the Company field when you add the contact?  I believe that if you specify a Company when creating your Contact, it will be added to the Contact sublist of the customer.

Comment: So obvious. Thank you! Incidentally, you answered before anyone on the official NetSuite forum did.